# Torch.cat memory explode

Tags: python, pytorch

I tried to replace Conv2d with this module on ResNet50.

```
class SubtractedConv(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self, input_ch, output_ch, kernels, stride=1):
        super().__init__()
        self.point_wise = nn.Conv2d(input_ch, output_ch//2, 1, bias=False, stride=stride)
        self.depth_wise = nn.Conv2d(output_ch // 2, output_ch // 2, kernels, groups=output_ch // 2, bias=False, padding=kernels // 2)
        self.low_pass = nn.Conv2d(output_ch // 2, output_ch // 2, kernels, bias=False, padding=kernels // 2)
    def forward(self, x):
        p = self.point_wise(x)
        d = self.depth_wise(p)
        d -= p 
        l = self.low_pass(p)
        x = torch.cat((d, l), 1)
        return x
```

The expected outputs should have same channel with normal Conv2d but I got cuda out of memory at torch.cat().
I wonder why? And how to deal with this?

I use Pytorch 0.4.0 and run on Tesla P100, image size 224*224, batch size 16.

In fact, something like this works on Keras and it has less parameters (16M in ResNet50 compare to 25M with normal Conv2D).

```
def subtractedconv(input_tensor, kernel_size, filters, stride=1):
    p = kl.Conv2D(filters//2, (1, 1), use_bias=False, strides=stride, padding='same')(input_tensor)
    d = DepthwiseConv2D(kernel_size, use_bias=False, padding='same')(p)
    d = kl.subtract([d, p])
    l = kl.Conv2D(filters//2, kernel_size, use_bias=False, padding='same')(p)
    x = kl.Concatenate(axis=-1)([d, l])
    return x
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem with PyTorch, most likely, are the intermediate tensors created, rather than `torch.cat` itself. In order to backpropagate through `nn.Conv2d`, you need to keep in memory the input to this operation. As you go through the layers, memory consumption increases (all intermediate results are kept). Now in your `forward` code you have three of them

```
p = self.point_wise(x) # x is kept
d = self.depth_wise(p) # p is kept
d -= p # here we do not need to keep d, because of derivative formula for subtraction
l = self.low_pass(p)
x = torch.cat((d, l), 1) # but since this goes into further processing, we will need to keep d anyway
```

Note that even though your operations may be computationally efficient (for instance have small kernels), they still require the same amount of memory to hold the input feature map - in other words, you pay for a large fixed cost for each `nn.Conv2d`, regardless of its own complexity. So, clearly, if you replace one `nn.Conv2d` with three, you can expect a roughly threefold increase in memory consumption.

There is a workaround for your case, though. Since your whole operation is linear (you only perform convolutions, which are linear, subtraction, which is linear and concatenation, which is in some sense linear), you can boil down this whole computation to a single convolution, with a carefully prepared kernel. If we consider the convolutions as linear operators and denote the `point_wise` operation with `P`, `depth_wise` with `D` and `low_pass` with `L`, we get that your forward computes `concatenate(Dx - Px, LPx)`, which can be simplified to `[concatenate(D-P, LP)]x`. So, you can precompute the kernel based on three sets of weights (corresponding to `point_wise`, `depth_wise` and `low_pass`) and then call [`nn.functional.conv2d`](https://pytorch.org/docs/master/nn.html#torch.nn.functional.conv2d) once. Implementing this precomputation is difficult though, as it requires quite complex transformations of shapes of the parameter tensors to preserve the exact semantics of your operation (to subtract the spatial kernel `D` from 1x1 kernel `P`, for instance). I tried getting this in 10 minutes and failed, but if that's very important, consider asking on PyTorch forums or letting me know in comments.

As to why Keras deals with it, I don't know for sure, but a strong guess is that it's thanks to TensorFlow. Unlike PyTorch, TensorFlow uses (mainly) static computation graphs, which can be analyzed ahead of time and optimized. I would expect that TensorFlow recognizes the sequence of three linear operators and combines them in one, or at least makes partial use of their linearity to optimize memory usage.

Comment: I still don't get the idea. Could you share what you tried?
But well, since Keras is usable I would use it for this task. But this might be useful in the future.